# Why is Logcat not showing logs for my physical device but showing logs for the emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am unable to find logs in Logcat when I try to log on physical device but when I try to log on Emulator the Logs are completely visible.

I tried INVALIDATE CACHES removed and connected the device again and again and all the possible solutions. But nothing is working for me.

Now I am expecting to get a desired solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the connected devices via `adb` command

```
adb devices
```

and then choose the one using `-s`. See https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#directingcommands

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've selected the physical device from the logcat's dropdown.

[image: Logcat]